# Do I have to mention that I used ChatGPT to polish my paper?

Tags: publications, ethics, writing, generative-ai

Just finished my paper writing for my PhD. My supervisor is not happy with my academic writing and suggested using ChatGPT to polish my writing.
Does that go against any writing ethics and may result in problems now or in the future?

do I have to mention that I used ChatGPT in my paper?

Comment: Do you think presenting text not written by you as yours is plagiarism?

Comment: Perhaps depends on the field. The writing style in a good Physical Review Letter is very different from a good collage English paper.

Comment: @JonCuster your typo "good collage English paper" is actually funny and appropriate here!  A ChatGPT paper is likely a collage rather than a college paper :)

Comment: Perhaps pastiche is even better? But, <sigh> on my bad...